# How to pass array parameter from seeder into Factory?

Tags: laravel, faker

In laravel 9 app I need to create dummy data with factory with aften repeating url for using in groups. So in seeder I have :

```php
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $itemsCount = 50;
        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
        $refUrls = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < (int) ($itemsCount / 5); $i++) {
            $refUrls[] = $faker->url(); // I generate such array
        }

        BannerClickedCount::factory()
            ->count($itemsCount)
            ->create(['refUrls'=> $refUrls]);
```

and pass it to factory as parameter, but it does not work as BannerClickedCount model has no refUrls field and I can not use it as passed
parameter into database/factories/BannerClickedCountFactory.php:

```php
class BannerClickedCountFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = BannerClickedCount::class;
    
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition($refUrls = []) // That is empty array
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($refUrls, ' -1 extends Factory $refUrls::'));
        ...
```

How can I pass array parameter from seeder into Factory ?

**ADDTIVE CODE :**
I tried to modify my code, but got error :

```
  current(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given

  at database/seeders/banner_clicked_countsWithInitData.php:32
     28▕         }
     29▕         BannerClickedCount::factory()->count($itemsCount)
     30▕             ->state(new Sequence(
     31▕             // generate a sequence of reference URLs from the array
  ➜  32▕                 fn () => current($refUrls),
     33▕                 $refUrls
     34▕             ))
     35▕             ->create([]);
     36▕         /* BannerClickedCount::factory()

  1   database/seeders/banner_clicked_countsWithInitData.php:32
```

**ADDTIVE CODE # 2:**

$refUrls in my code is an array of strings :

```
$refUrls[] = $faker->url();
```

So I think I do not need explode be used, but with I remade seeder file :

```
$itemsCount = 10;
$faker           = \Faker\Factory::create();
$refUrls = [];
for($i = 0; $i< (int)($itemsCount/2) ; $i++) {
    $refUrls[] = $faker->url();
}
\Log::info(varDump($refUrls, ' -1 RUN Factory $refUrls::'));

BannerClickedCount::factory()->count($itemsCount)
    ->state(new Sequence(
        current($refUrls),
        $refUrls
    ))
    ->create([]); // Error pointing at this line !
```

I got error :

```
  array_merge(): Argument #2 must be of type array, string given

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:438
    434▕             if ($state instanceof Closure) {
    435▕                 $state = $state->bindTo($this);
    436▕             }
    437▕ 
  ➜ 438▕             return array_merge($carry, $state($carry, $parent));
    439▕         }, $this->definition());
    440▕     }
    441▕ 
    442▕     /**

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\{closure}()

      +2 vendor frames 
  12  database/seeders/banner_clicked_countsWithInitData.php:52
...
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I salved the isue with defining custom method setRefUrl in factory :

```
class BannerClickedCountFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = BannerClickedCount::class;

    public function definition($refUrls = [])
    {
        $locales = config('translatable.locales', []);
        return [
            'banner_id' => $this->faker->randomElement(Banner::all())['id'],
            'locale' => $this->faker->randomElement($locales),
            'user_id' => $this->faker->randomElement([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
            'ip'        => '127.0.0.1',
            'created_at' => $this->faker
                ->dateTimeBetween('-1 week', '-1 minute')
                ->format('Y-m-d G:i'),
        ];
    }
    public function setRefUrl($refUrls)
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) use($refUrls) {
            return [
                'ref_url' => $this->faker->randomElement($refUrls)
            ];
        });
    }
```

and calling it in the seeder :

```
$itemsCount = 200;
$faker           = \Faker\Factory::create();
$refUrls = [];
for($i = 0; $i< (int)($itemsCount/20) ; $i++) {
    $refUrls[] = $faker->url();
}
BannerClickedCount::factory()->count($itemsCount)->setRefUrl($refUrls)
```

Answer (score 1):

modify the definition method of your BannerClickedCountFactory class to accept an additional parameter that will receive the array of reference URLs. And in your seeder, you can pass the $refUrls array to the BannerClickedCountFactory.

```
class BannerClickedCountFactory extends Factory
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @param array $refUrls
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition(array $refUrls = [])
    {
        return [
            // define the default state of your model
            'ref_url' => count($refUrls) > 0 ? array_shift($refUrls) : null,
            // other fields...
        ];
    }
}
```

Seeder

```
BannerClickedCount::factory()
    ->count($itemsCount)
    ->state(new Sequence(
        // generate a sequence of reference URLs from the array
        fn () => current(explode(',', $refUrls)),
        $refUrls
    ))
    ->create();
```

Comment: Please look at ADDTIVE CODE

Comment: current() function expects an array as its argument, but in your code, $refUrls is being passed as a string.
Change current($refUrls) to current(explode(',', $refUrls)) in your seeder file. This will convert the comma-separated string into an array of URLs and then return the current URL from the array.

Comment: i updated my code for seeder file

Comment: Please look at ADDTIVE CODE # 2